# Terms and Conditions on checkout via block

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm trying to load the Terms and Conditions on the Checkout page via a `cms/page` block. **(SALES -> Terms and Conditions -> new condition -> Content)**

```
{{block type="cms/page" page_id="agb"}}
```

I'm using this code on a second store as well and it's working just fine. I checked the permissions at **System -> Permissions -> Blocks.**

`cms/page` is set to allowed. I tried loading the page on this way on a normal page and that works just fine. 
I had a look into the PHP Error log and there is no error what so ever. Browser console is free of errors as well. 
At the moment it just gives back the code in the checkout I put in to the content field.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223249/how-to-create-custom-checkbox-field-for-term-and-conditions-in-one-page-checkout/344623#344623

Answer (score 0):

just create static block and call in checkout template like this

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('brands_logos')->toHtml(); ?>
```

app/design/frontend/your-package/default/template/checkout